# Storyboard as local var vs instance field

Tags: c#

I have a storyboard that I need to start and stop throughout my program.
Since it's only used in two methods:

```
        private void beginStoryBoard()
        {
            UserControl loadingAnimation = Application.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("loadingAnimation") as UserControl;
            Storyboard storyboard = loadingAnimation.FindResource("ProgressAnimation") as Storyboard;
            storyboard.Begin();
        }

        private void stopStoryBoard()
        {
            UserControl loadingAnimation = Application.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("loadingAnimation") as UserControl;
            Storyboard storyboard = loadingAnimation.FindResource("ProgressAnimation") as Storyboard;
            storyboard.Stop();
        }
```

Is it better to keep the Storyboard as a local var in each method? Or should I create a private instance field instead? Below is what I think the pros/cons are (please correct me if need be), which situation would be best?

```
With a local var:
Pro: the var gets scraped once the method completes
Con: extra methods need to be called each time

With an instnace field:
Pro: FindResource() method needs to be called only once
Con: The instance field will take up memory throughout the life of the application
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With a local var: 
>   Pro: the var gets scraped once the method completes 
>   Con: extra methods need to be called each time

The Pro here doesn't apply -- you are not assigning any new memory, just creating a pointer to an existing object.  That object's memory will not be freed, as long as `MainWindow`, which still has a reference to the storyboard instance, is open.

The Con hardly matters -- the method to lookup the Storyboard object will only run once each time the animation runs, and in any case, it (I'm guessing) will only take a few ticks of the CPU to look up an object in a hash table (Resource Dictionary).

Bottom line: [this is a micro-optimization, and so it doesn't matter](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html).

Comment: I see what you mean.
So since the storyboard object exists no matter what, creating a local var and pointing to it doesn't make a difference memory-wise since it's just a pointer.

So which would be better in terms of memory, or neither makes much of a difference?

Which would be better in terms of speed? Surely using a instance field would be faster since you wouldn't need to call the FindResource() method (twice) in each call to begin/end storyboard()?

Comment: @Backwards_Dave but the `FindResource` is a hash lookup -- that's about as quick as you can get.  So sure, maybe a bit slower, but it's not like you're calling it every render frame where small differences really matter.  So really the difference is negligible -- do whatever is best from a code readability/maintenance standpoint.